# How to change the name of a record set in Route 53 using python boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

I am able to perform actions such as updating the value of a record set in Route 53, but can't find an api to rename an existing record set using python boto3. The `Name` parameter in the documentation is the `Name` of the record set which we want to change. How do I specify the new name for the record set?

See: [boto3: `change_resource_record_sets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of my record files, which I used to update the route53 recordset. Hope it helps

```
try:
    route53 = boto3.client('route53')
    route53.change_resource_record_sets(
        HostedZoneId = hosted_zone_id,
        ChangeBatch={
            'Changes': [
                {
                    'Action': 'UPSERT',
                    'ResourceRecordSet': {
                        'Name': record_name,
                        'Type': 'A',
                        'ResourceRecords': [
                            {
                                'Value': ipForRecord
                            }
                        ],
                        'TTL': 300
                    }
                }
            ]
        } 
    )

except Exception as e:
    print 'Exception while updating cloud 53 record'
    print e
```

Comment: Thanks! One point though, an added step to delete the original record set would be required, no? This would create a new record set with the given ip.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the `Name` is the unique identifier of the Record Set.

Therefore, there is no capability to change the name.

You will need to **create a new Record Set** with the different name.

Comment: ...and delete the old one, in the same batch.